# How to edit/write to my jenkins console logs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, logparser

I am new to jenkins. I am trying to add a new line in my jenkins log console to display the Application name with its sub-component like (Datamax - Crawler) so that i can run a query on entire jenkins log files and filter out using sed/awk to get application name

I tried using log parser plugin where i change Global Configuration (/jenkins/configure). There is a section "Console Output Parsing". In description i put, for example, : "Rules1" and in "Parsing Rules File" - "This is for Application: Datamax-Crawler".

And then, i tried updating jenkinsfile at the end of the pipeline in the post phase.

```
 post {
        always {
            logParser ([
                projectRulePath: 'Rules1',
                parsingRulesPath: '',
                showGraphs: true, 
                unstableOnWarning: true, 
                useProjectRule: true
                ])
            emailext (
            to: 'xxx@xxx.com',
        attachLog: 'true',
                replyTo: '$DEFAULT_REPLYTO', 
                subject: '$DEFAULT_SUBJECT',
                body: '$DEFAULT_CONTENT',
                mimeType: 'text/html'
            );
         }
       }
```

Note: I have attached the console log picture where i would like the result like this in green highlight at the beginning

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems a pretty simple way to do it would be using ansiColor plugin with echo command.

```
pipeline{
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Example') {
            steps {
                ansiColor('xterm') {
                    echo "\u001B[1m\u001B[32mThis is for Datamax-Crawler\u001B[0m"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rahul. Do i specify a seperate stage for this activity along with other stages that i have in my jenkins script

Comment: No, you can just use the code in steps block and paste it in the steps block of the very first stage in your code.